# Creating a class and creating an object for the class which is a vector and a string(vector<string>)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector

im trying to creat a programe which get infinite students and infinite course name for each student and then it prints them like this:

```
student 1:
coursename1
coursename2
....
student2:
coursename1
coursename2
....
```

but I don't know how to do any of the above please help

Comment: he looks to be new to C++

Comment: Homework question much?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to provide additional operations for users or for the users manage, you have to create a class, like this one below:

```
class student
{
private: 
  string m_name;
  vector<string> m_courses;
public:
  student() : m_name(), m_courses() { }
  student(string name) : m_name( name ), m_courses() { }
  vector<string> get_courses();
  vector<string> &add_course( string course_name );
  vector<string> &remove_course( string course_name );
  vector<string> &remove_course( int course_index );
  string get_name() const;
};
```

and for creating a `students_manager` class, you can write a collection class:

```
class students_mgr
{
private:
  vector<student> m_students;
public:
  students_mgr();
  students_mgr( vector<student> &students);
  void add_student( student &s );
  void add_student( string student_name );
  void remove_student( student &s );
  void remove_student( string student_name );
  void remove_student( int student_index );  
};
```

I have also written **some of the methods'** implementations, to give you a starting point:

```
vector<string> &student::add_course( string course_name )
{
  // check if the student is already in a course_name
  for( auto it = m_courses.begin(); it != m_courses.end(); ++it )
  {
    if( *it == course_name ) return this->m_courses;
  }

  this->m_courses.push_back( course_name );
  return this->m_courses;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I see now. I was very tired yesterday, and I wrote it in a hurry

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to create your own class to do this. Learn how to use [`std:vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which is a sequence container that encapsulates dynamic size arrays..

You can try the following data structure:

```
vector<string> names;
vector<vector<string>> courses;
```

Or simply:

```
vector<pair<string, vector<string>>> names_and_courses;
            ^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
              |           |
            names      courses
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are great, but something a little simpler might involve a `struct` and a few loops.  Think of each student with a name and a list (aka vector) of courses.

```
struct student{
    string name;
    vector<string> courses;
};
```

In your main method you'll want something that will hold an "infinite" list of students, like a vector of type student possibly named students (`vector<student> students`).

I'll let you figure out the loops and the user-input verification, but I would recommend the following:

```
student s; //gives you a 'student' to work with
s.name = "student name"; //how to assign a name to the student
s.courses.push_back("course name"); //this is how you access the student's courses and add them
```

Once you have the student's name and course information, you need to add the student to a separate infinite list.  You'd do this by calling:

```
students.push_back(s);
```

This should be enough to get you started.  Please feel free to ask any follow up questions.  I would recommend this tutorial on [Structures](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson7.html) and this documentation on [Vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)